# How to get rid of stuck terminal error

Tags: terminal, error

I don't exactly remember what I did last night, but ever since I get this message everytime I launch terminal. Not that it stops me from doing anything, it's just really annoying. Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Terminal error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your profile files (~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile, etc) to see what is being run when you launch your shell and remove references to zsh. To see exactly what is being executed when you launch your shell, execute your shell with the `-x` option. Also make sure your Terminal shell is set correctly in Preferences.

Comment: I have no expertise in working with terminal but I checked the .bash_profile in my home directory which appears to be totally empty. Any specific steps that I can follow ?

Comment: @nashmaniac Make sure that the shell in Terminal → Preferences → General is set to the shell you intend. [Other profile files to check](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/142631/37797)

Comment: Setting the shell to default in preferences did the trick